# How can I test my server has .net 3.5 SP1 installed?

Tags: .net-3.5, configuration, testing

Is there a way I can upload a file to my web server to test whether .net 3.5 SP1 was installed properly?

Maybe use a new feature or something?

Comment: Duplicate. See Kev's post for links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed a fair bit:

[How do I tell if .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198931/how-do-i-tell-if-net-3-5-sp1-is-installed)

[Best Way To Determine If .NET 3.5 Is Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178/best-way-to-determine-if-net-3-5-is-installed)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `Web.config` file and see if the assembly exists:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think, there is not.
But you can write a pure .net 3.5 aspx webpage and upload it and request it. If it works as worked at your machine, server has got proper 3.5 :)